# How do I go back to the first hand?

Tags: phrase-requests

> If you think of depression as biochemical, you may use it as an excuse not to act the way you should. On the other hand, if you think of it as psychological, you may blame yourself for what is outside your control. **But, on the one hand again,** the perceived inevitability can make you even more depressed.

I'd like an alternative to what I wrote in bold that

1. doesn't have the redundant "but", and
2. still clearly alerts the reader to the move to the first hand.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to move the second biochemical to join the first.  "...the way you should, and, even worse, the perceived inevitability can make you even more depressed. On the other hand..." Is that possible?

Comment: @Hugh You are right, but no, that is not possible. I'd like to emphasize the hesitation between ideas. Also, I'd like the solution to work in speech as well, when you can't go back and edit what you said.

Comment: Then perhaps re-iterate 'biochemical.'  "With the biochemical explanation again, the perceived inevitability... "

Comment: As already mentioned, don't jump back and forth like this in the first place. Remove *But, on the one hand again* from the third sentence and join what remains to the first sentence. It's really awkward otherwise.

Comment: You could write 'in the first case' the perceived inevitability can make you even more depressed.

Comment: What if you simplify that phrase to 'Then again...'? https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/then+again

Comment: @Alex_ander **then again** is much too informal to be used in this case, unfortunately.

Comment: The expression 'on the one hand' is an idiom. And the idiom expects just another input - 'on the other hand'. Usually the idiom is used as a contrast, as a set of balances. Going back to the first hand is clumsy and (in my view) not idiomatic. Semantically, it is better to state what relates to Condition A, then state what relates to Condition B. Swapping back and forth is tedious to the mind (again, in my view).

Comment: I would say "then again" is in the same register as "on the other hand", so if you're trying to avoid informality you should probably rethink the whole "handedness" concept. Also recast the sentence in third person, rather than second. And "act the way [one] should" should probably be something like "act appropriately". And so forth. (In other words, your current passage is quite informal and conversational, and "then again" fits in perfectly.)

Comment: From the biochemical perspective, however...

Answer (score 1):

I use this structure fairly often in scientific talks, and agree that it is useful to set the situation out clearly as a dichotomy, before expanding each of the alternatives in turn.

However, I have found that continuing to use the the "on the one hand / on the other hand" **is very confusing for the audience**. I am constantly asked to remind everyone which hand was which. Indeed the value of the phrases is not really as a shorthand, but as a way to emphasize the dichotomy. Repeating the actual word is better both for clarity and rhetorically.

So for your third sentence I would write, "If it *is* biochemical, then the perceived inevitability can make you even more depressed."